# Does my PC have USB 2.0 or 1.0?

Tags: usb

I would post an image from my device manager, but I need more rep points.

The things it says under USB are -

Generic USB Hub
USB Mass Storage Device
USB Root Hub
Intel chipset USB Universal Host Controller (with varying number IDs)

And how do i know if I need to update drivers please?

Comment: We need more information to answer this question.

Comment: your pc almost certainly does not have USB 1.0, its more likely to be 1.1 or 2.0, and anything reasonably modern has 1.0. What would be really useful would be the *actual* issues you are having, and more information on your hardware.

Comment: just bought a second hand dual quad core xeon 20 gb ram, but its fairly old i would guess, just takes about 5 minutes to copy a gigabyte or so, so quite slow

Comment: @Seb: Check your system/motherboard manual for detailed specs.

Comment: No manual, dont think I've ever seen one for any motherboard I've ever had - but this is second hand comp